# datalist input element loses cursor after datalist list attribute is set on ios safari

Tags: javascript, html, datalist

i have an html datalist element for which i am trying to only show the autocomplete list when more than two characters are entered in the field.  on desktop, you can type from 0 to infinity characters with the input never losing focus and the list appearing just fine.  however, for mobile (specifically- iOS safari), when the character length of the input hits 3, the cursor disappears despite the input still having focus.  the user must click on the input again to continue his search.  i will mention that the safari browser is presenting the user with some unrelated autocomplete results until this length of 3 is hit.  here is the listener on the datalist that governs my intended behavior:

```
  // Only show auto-complete results for greater than 2 characters.
  searchNameInput.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
    const input = e.target;
    const list = input.getAttribute('data-list');
    input.value.length > 2 ? input.setAttribute('list', list) : input.removeAttribute('list');

    // Unrelated code (i think):
    if (!input.value.length)
      filtersProxy.searchName = { name: '', city: '', stateProvince: '' };
  });
```

here is what the browser looks like after 3 characters have been typed.  notice the input field has no cursor.  the datalist actual list hasn't appeared yet either.

[image: example]

i've tried using a setTimeout to return the focus to the element after every keyup event to no avail.  this one has me stumped!

Comment: I have the same issue on MacOS Safari, this may be a bug, I would like to know if there is hack to fix this.

Comment: @jcubic a snippet would really help

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy mine demo is here https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/abdWvvp this is the code I'm working on, original version is here https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/YbYpqO it complete the tag if you start typing foo or bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a terrible hack for you.

First, create a fake input field:

```
const fakeInput = document.createElement('input')
fakeInput.setAttribute('type', 'text')
fakeInput.style.position = 'absolute'
fakeInput.style.opacity = 0
fakeInput.style.height = 0
fakeInput.style.fontSize = '16px'
document.body.prepend(fakeInput)
fakeInput.focus()
```

Next, use `setTimeout` to set the focus to your `input`, because setting it directly won't work:

```
if(input.value.length > 2) {
    if(!input.hasAttribute('list')) {
      fakeInput.focus();
      input.setAttribute('list', list);
      setTimeout(() => input.focus(), 10);
    }
} else input.removeAttribute('list');
```

Voila.

Comment: Thanks this is something I can test, will check tomorrow on BrowserStack how this works. Looks very promising but need to check first.

Comment: I'm not sure how this suppose to work, I've played a bit and it seems that if you focus the input it get focus but don't trigger data list. Here is my small library [Tagger](https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/abdWvvp?editors=0110) that I'm working on. Can you create demo where this works? Even using Stack Snippet, something I can run.

Comment: @jcubic Do you have a version of the code that exhibits the characteristics from the question?

Comment: Yes tagger demo I've linked, it include the hole library so I can test in BrowserStack. it have data list added with completion and when there are more then 2 characters list attribute is added (using your code) but the completion is now showing up because you need to physically click on the input for it show up.

Comment: Can you help me reproduce by showing a version of the code where the list appears? I do not see the list displaying at all. I also noticed that in your code, the `input.setAttribute('list', list);` is *inside* the `setTimeout()` call, which is not intended.

Comment: that was my attempt to fix the issue having input outside work the same, you need to type "foo" or "bar" as tag name and it should complete the word, but the data list don't show up until I click with mouse. If you will be able to fix the function _toggle_completion so it work it would be great. Or just your example in stack snippet that actually show the completion on Safari and on Chrome because it seems that your code don't in any browser. Do you have some demo that you was testing this before you posted the answer?

Comment: @jcubic Sure, open this URL in Safari or Mobile Safari: https://confirmed-recondite-tank.glitch.me/ The original text box is on the left; after three characters, focus moves away. The fixed text box is on the right; focus stays on the box as the user continues to type past three characters.

Comment: There are no actual list or am I missing something, the problem is that list is not visible, the it should work with both list and focus. Your code work only in focus if list attribute is added but it don't open the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug. I don't think it can be fixed until Apple rolls out a patch update.

Because the issue also appears on MacOS Safari, and iOS is based on MacOS (MacOS Safari and iOS Safari are very similar internally just with different user interfaces) it is probably a bug with the way Safari handles renders text boxes and won't be fixed until Apple gets to fixing their HTML rendering engine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a quick fix for the lost focus of data list on Safari

Here is the code with the fix for my library:

https://github.com/jcubic/tagger/pull/24

to fix the issue instead of removing the attribute you just set it to an invalid value.

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, it seems the bug is still there. Here is a workaround using the selectionStart property of the input tag.

```
const p = input.selectionStart;
if(input.value.length > 2) {
    if(!input.hasAttribute('list')) input.setAttribute('list', list);
}
else input.removeAttribute('list');
input.selectionStart = p;
```